# convert string to date and find difference in minutes

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a sample value in column as `20230420110004` in GCP Bigquery. This is the time in utc `2023-04-20 11:00:04 UTC`.

Now i want to compare the this value(20230420110004) with the current utc and want to get the difference in minutes. so if the current utc time is 2023-04-20 14:05:56.157508 UTC(using the current_timestamp() function), I should get the difference as 185 minutes(3 hours 5 minutes).

what i tried

```
TIMESTAMP_DIFF(cast(timestring as date), current_timestamp(), MINUTE)
```

Comment: and what is the problem

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast a string to a timestamp or date. The right function is `parse_timestamp` and you need to provide the date [format](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions).

```sql
WITH tbl AS (
    SELECT "20230420110004" as timestring
)
SELECT
    timestring,
    parse_timestamp("%Y%m%d%H%M%S", timestring),
    TIMESTAMP_DIFF(
        parse_timestamp("%Y%m%d%H%M%S", timestring), 
        current_timestamp(),
        MINUTE
    )
FROM tbl
```